# TextInput Update and state modification slow

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have made a React page. It initially gets data from my API, and stores it in state. The parent component makes a TextInput in a component for each row of data.

The TextInput value is from a prop. The onChange calls a method on the parent (through a prop given to the TextInput), which finds the appropriate index to update, updates it, then setState. It also sends a PUT to my API to update the data.

However it is pretty sluggish when typing. I can type fast and you can see it having a delay sometimes.

Any ideas?

```
update_sound(sound_transcript, sound_id) {
  var index = this.state.board.sounds.findIndex(sound => {
    return sound.id === sound_id;
  });

  this.state.board.sounds[index].sound_transcript = sound_transcript;
  this.setState({
    board: this.state.board
  });

  axios
    .put("/api/v1/sounds/" + sound_id, {
      sound_transcript: sound_transcript
    })
    .then(response => {
      //Handle success
      console.log("Update success");
    })
    .catch(error => {
      //Handle error
      console.log("Update error: " + error);
    })
    .then(() => {
      //Always executed
    });
}

<textarea
  className="soundPlayer_text_input"
  value={this.props.sound.sound_transcript}
  onChange={this.soundOnChange}
/>;

soundOnChange(event) {
  console.log("soundOnChange");
  this.props.update_sound(event.target.value, this.props.sound.id);
}
```

Thanks

Comment: You are making a remote request in every keystroke. It is better to change your logic somehow. Also, do not mutate your state like this: `this.state.board.sounds[index].sound_transcript = sound_transcript;`

Comment: Should I try to figure out immutability-helper, or make a copy and change that?

Comment: `copy` is a **thing** you should avoid in React/Redux/Anything_else_you_dont_want_mutation. For example, forget about direct assigning (never do this!), even `Object.assign`, or spread syntax or methods like `.map` only do shallow copies. If you change a nested property in the copied object then you will mutate the original one. So, you need to combine all those methods. I can't say much about `immutability-helper` since I don't use it. But, if you learn the basics and best practices you won't need it.

Comment: So how do you change data if you're changing state? Idk how to even ask these questions, it is starting to become demented

Comment: I tried
this.setState((state) => ({ [state.board.sounds[index].sound_transcript]: sound_transcript }));   which I w

Comment: I've provided some examples in your other question. Again, most of the time you can use some combinations of `Object.assign` or spread syntax and `.map` or `.filter` according to the situation.